# Angular conditional polling with time interval

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, polling

I have a polling scenario like below where I'm polling every 1 secs to a rest API and waits for a result

```
interval(1000)
      .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        switchMap(() => this.itemService.getItems(shopId))
      )
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
        
        if(response && response.status = false) {
            // stop polling
        }
        
        );
      });
```

polling part is working without an issue. The issue is I want the polling to stop when I get a response and its status is false. How to change this code to conditionally stop polling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can use [takeWhile](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takewhile)

```
 Pool()
    {
      interval(1000)
      .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        switchMap(() => this.itemService.getItems(shopId)),
        takeWhile(response=> response.status == true) //takeWhile(response=> response.status)
      )
      .subscribe(response => {
    
      });
```

}

Comment: When I get a response first I want to process the response do some operations and then stops polling, with this polling stops before I process the response. How can we change this to other way around? :)

Comment: after processing u can just call pool again.
there are other ways. doing it reactivity but trust me this is simplest

Comment: This is really simple logic for polling. But, how to handle errors? If api fails due to any reason, I still should be able to poll at the same interval.